# deleting directories from a file system on basis of date elixir

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have been saving jpegs to `seaweedfs` within a directory structure as

```
Camera-name/recordings/year/month/day/hour/minutes_seconds_000.jpg
```

I am creating a delete Endpoint in `phoenix`, I already have a `def` written which is giving me all available jpegs within 2 dates range, with timestamps. Such as If a user selects starting date as `1525046400` (30-04-2018) and ending date as `1525737599` (07-05-2018), and the method is giving me such details as

```
{"snapshots":[{"notes":"Evercam Proxy","motion_level":null,"created_at":1525042801},{"notes":"Evercam Proxy","motion_level":null,"created_at":1525042803},{"notes":"Evercam Proxy","motion_level":null,"created_at":1525042805},{"notes":"Evercam Proxy","motion_level":null,"created_at":1525042807}]}
```

If I take the first object from `snapshots`, and its `created_at` date, convert it while considering the above `seaweedfs` directory structure as

```
directory_path =
  timestamp
  |> Calendar.DateTime.Parse.unix!
  |> Calendar.Strftime.strftime!("%Y/%m/%d/%H/%M_%S_000.jpg")
"#{seaweedfs}/#{camera_exid}/snapshots/recordings/#{directory_path}"
```

This will give me the direct link to the JPEG in the file system. And I can delete it through

```
hackney = [pool: :seaweedfs_download_pool, recv_timeout: 30_000_000]
HTTPoison.delete!("#{url}?recursive=true", [], hackney: hackney)
```

Here is the issue. If I am getting snapshots between 2 date ranges, and the date range is more than an hour. or a full hour. or a day. or a month. then I have an option to delete the directory, full directory instead of a jpeg. But I don't know through which logic, I can do it.

for example: Collect all `created_at` from snapshot object. then group them first, all with the same hour, then count if it's a full hour. then delete the hour directory instead of each file separately, Same as if created_at date after grouping making a full day then delete a day instead of each hour. or file separately.

Its slightly confused problem, But I am not asking for a handwritten solution but suggestions, who You will do it if you are solving it?